# Error de sintaxis al tratar de generar una función con arrays y ciclos de iteracion

Tags: javascript

Dado un array con fechas, utilice un ciclo para poder rellenar otro array vació, luego que genere aparte otro ciclo y que allí muestre la edad y si es menor de edad, justo mayor, y mayor de edad. Y por ultimo que cree una función llamada printFullAge que recibe la matriz de años como argumento que tenga todo lo anterior dentro y devuelva una matriz de valores booleanos verdadero / falso: verdadero si la persona es mayor de edad (> = 18 años) y falso si no (<18 años) y me encuentro trabado con la codificación de dicho planteo. Desde ya gracias a quien me ayude!

```
var yearsBorn = [2001, 1990, 1985, 1946, 1998, 1963];
var refill = [];

function printFullAge() {

  for (var i = 0; i <= yearsBorn.length - 1; i++) {
    refill.push(yearsBorn[i]);
  }

  var i = 0;
  while (i < yearsBorn.length) {
    var age = 2018 - yearsBorn[i];

    if (age === 18) {
      console.log("full age" + " " + age + " " + true);
    } else if (age < 18) {
      console.log("kid" + " " + age + " " + false);
    } else {
      console.log("Mayor" + " " + age + " " + true);
    }
    i++;
  }
}
function yearsBorn.printFullAge();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente te marca error; por que intentas hacer que el arreglo que contiene los años acceda a una función, segundo no necesitas en la última línea de código declarar de nuevo function, basta con que escribas el nombre de la misma y los paréntesis y con eso basta para que funcione mira

```js
var yearsBorn = [2001, 1990, 1985, 1946, 1998, 1963];
var refill = [];

function printFullAge() {

  for (var i = 0; i <= yearsBorn.length - 1; i++) {
    refill.push(yearsBorn[i]);
  }

  var i = 0;
  while (i < yearsBorn.length) {
    var age = 2018 - yearsBorn[i];

    if (age === 18) {
      console.log("full age" + " " + age + " " + true);
    } else if (age < 18) {
      console.log("kid" + " " + age + " " + false);
    } else {
      console.log("Mayor" + " " + age + " " + true);
    }
    i++;
  }
}
printFullAge()
```

Comment: muchas gracias! eso era lo que no entendia